# Technique for deferring CSS

Tags: html, css

I am in the process of adding my critical CSS to the head and deferring the rest. When adding CSS to the head, should I also remove that same CSS from my main CSS sheet or leave it as is?

For example:

```
<head>
     <style>
         .red{color: red;}
         .yellow{color: yellow;}
     </style>
</head>
```

My CSS sheet:

```
.red{color: red;}
.yellow{color: yellow;}
.black{color:black;}
.orange{color:orange}
.green{color:green}
```

So, should I remove `.red` and `.yellow` classes from my CSS sheet? I originally figured yes, but I ran into some issues with overrides in my main sheet and was wondering if it was a standard technique to remove them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you move them from your main style sheet to a `<style>` tag?

Comment: @bowl0stu for performance reasons. I'm trying to load the critical css on page load and defer everything below the page fold since my actual css sheet is rather large and is being flagged as a performance issue on page speed insights.

Comment: The [PageSpeed site has an example](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery#example) showing how to inline, and it does not mention removing CSS from the file.

Comment: Hopefully you don't intend on re-using any of the css you put in your `<head>`. Copy pasting css snippets across pages and then trying to do a styling update later on will be regrettable.

Answer (score 0):

Keep `.red{color: red;} .yellow{color: yellow;}` them in your style sheet but also include them in `<head>` so browser do not wait for style sheet to load and render elements using code found in `<head>` section. If these rules are not begin used in other pages then you can remove them to save file size.

Basically critical CSS is to render above the fold content as soon as possible so if you're serving the styles early then it's better.

You should inline all your CSS rules if file size of css is less than 20kb.

Comment: a style sheet size of 20KB seems like an arbitrary figure. What resource(s) influenced this number?

Comment: upvoting bowl0stu, not because I feel exceptional need to question the listed figure, but because I really want to know what the technical context for that heuristic is.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the browsers will not display a page until the stylesheets have been fetched, so moving one part to a `style` tag will do more bad than good as there will now be two places where the styling has to be maintained. [This post](https://jakearchibald.com/2016/link-in-body/) discusses about this behaviour across different browsers and a way of deferring CSS.

But then the question is, is this a very critical performance consideration you have to take in account? Stylesheets tend to have several dozen KB and with the bandwidth nowadays it would take a few milliseconds to be downloaded. If this matters to you as much, you may benefit from following the post linked above as your approach will lead to different results across browsers.

Comment: The asker specified in comments that the css _is_ a performance issue. As for the _how_ of stylesheet deferral, I was able to find [this page](https://www.giftofspeed.com/defer-loading-css/) that suggests using javascript to deffer the css load.

Comment: I know he mentioned it is a performance issue. There are many other ways of improving site load speed than deferring CSS – why do you think `defer` and `async` are not implemented for `<link>` tag?

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter the linked post does exactly the same only in higher detail. Please read the full answer *and* the linked post before commenting.